# How do I reopen an open program on a linux server, with ssh connection in Powershell

Tags: linux, powershell, ssh, server, minecraft

Basically I have a linux server, that I can connect to using `ssh -i *pvKey* *user@host*`.
When I'm connected I can open a java application, like I have. The linux server stays open 24/7 and I believe any application I open does the same. How do I reopen an open application if I close windows powershell.
Let's say I go to bed and close windows Powershell, I believe the java application will stay open during the night, which is what I want. How do I reopen that java program again after connecting to the server, so I can continue sending commands in the java application.

For more specific information: The java application I'm talking about is a minecraft server, which I want to leave on 24/7 (with some restarts obv). I want to be able to reopen the java program of the mc-server that has stayed open, so that I can send more commands and possibly restart the mc-server, without having to log into it in minecraft, stopping it, and reopening it in powershell.

This is the first time I try to work with a linux server and powershell, so please excuse my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Your remote shell automatically kills all processes that are running in the shell when you exit the shell.
I would probably use [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) for this usecase.

Comment: Is screen like a program that does the same as powershell but doesn't automatically close processes? Because I don't understand why Powershell closes my mc-server when I close it, the linux server runs 24/7 and is like a second computer right? So it should keep applications open if I open them. Do you know if it is possible to exit powershell without closing the java program (mc-server)?

If screen is a Software, where can I download it, and how do I connect to my linux server with it?

Comment: PowerShell is running on Windows. It can't open or close anything on Linux. When you ssh to Linux you start a session there. If you close that session, then any processes running under it are terminated. screen is a way of saying "I'll be back"

Comment: Yes stark, I have read a little more about it, and have managed to install it on the linux instance. I have then typed "screen" and it did something. Though when I do Ctrl+a it doesnt give me the list of commands. Do I have to sudo the linux server to do Ctrl+a itself? If yes how do I do that?

Comment: Ok I've done it. I understand how sessions and programs in screen work and know how to deattach/attach to sessions or quit sessions. My server is running perfectly now. Thank you for all the help. Couldn't have done it without you.